# Does the DMA tool do absolutely no changes on the source sql server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-migration-assistant

I am planning to use the DMA tool for migrating sql server 2016 to sql server 2019. Both on-prem.

I will be carrying out a test migration this weekend, followed by deleting the dbs and logins from the target server and re-running the DMA tool next month as the final migration.

I just wanted some confirmation as to whether the DMA tool does absolutely no changes on the source sql server?

Answer (score 1):

Simply running the DMA to gather data will only do that, gather data. It won't affect the underlying data architecture. I haven't used the tool to perform the actual migration, but from everything I understand, that won't affect the original database either.

Comment: The tool doesn't support data sync/cutover after the initial migration so I have to delete the dbs and logins after the initial migration; and then at a later date re-run the tool for final migration.

Comment: If you're going for a data sync process, there are other approaches, log shipping for example. Search for others as well.

Comment: Most of my dbs (count of dbs: 25) are in simple recovery model and the business doesn't want to switch to full recovery

Comment: You're going to have a very hard time doing both staying in simple compatibility mode (which will not maintain the log) and getting any kind of real time migration. The only way you can guarantee no data loss in this scenario is to first shut down the apps locally, then do the migration to the new servers.

Comment: Yes that's the plan, this question was specifically to ask whether source db is unaffected because I want to do 2 migrations. 1 this weekend as a test and the next one after a month (final).